# local account s3 images not rendering in hipchat?

Tags: amazon-s3, hipchat

I am pasting links to s3 images in hipchat room but they are not getting rendered, any idea why? I have my own AWS account in which i have hosted images in s3?
I think this might be because of access issues. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: What is happening when you paste your images in a browser are you able to see those images?

Comment: No i thought there should be some param through which we can give hipchat access to our local repo. But i figured there is no such thing. Only thing we can do is make the images public for everyone. So only if the image is public hipchat will render it, we can't connect it to some AWS accounts s3 bucket.